Ingress and Identity4
I have a cluster with an identity provider configured in Identity4 using NGINX. My systems need to access Identity4 and authenticate using OAuth and OpenID Connect.
I have two divergent situations and need support:
I have a .NET Framework site running on IIS 10. It can authenticate with id4 but fails to validate the JWT token when sending the token and claims.
I have another scenario with the same software converted to .NET Core, and it can authenticate without any issues, using the same NGINX and ingress.
Could there be something between NGINX, ingress, and IIS that might be causing this problem?
I was hoping that I would be able to make the connection, but it keeps looping and I can't validate it.

I do have a set of blogposts about troubleshooting authentication problems at https://nestenius.se/   I would also see the logs why the token validation fails.

As you have two different problems, I recommend posting two distinct questions here. Cookies is always an issue (you should always use HTTPS), do you have multiple instances of the client or IdentityServer in place? To troubleshoot JWTbearer problems, visit https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/
